# How can I Overwrite PHP file in Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

I am customizing the following theme.

https://github.com/inc2734/snow-monkey

And I'd like to add font - weight 300 to noto sans.

https://github.com/inc2734/snow-monkey/blob/9c817ca3c5176101db23185838260e2739163ebe/resources/src/css/foundation/_body/_body.php

"enqueue_noto_sans_jp.php" consists of the following code, only font-weight 400 is loaded.

```
<?php
/**
 * @package mimizuku
 * @author inc2734
 * @license GPL-2.0+
 */

namespace Inc2734\Mimizuku_Core\Helper;

/**
 * Enqueue Noto Sans JP
 *
 * @return void
 */
function enqueue_noto_sans_jp() {
    wp_enqueue_style(
        'noto-sans-jp',
        'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Noto+Sans+JP&subset=japanese',
        [],
        wp_get_theme()->get( 'Version' )
    );
}
```

I tried changing "enqueue_noto_sans_jp.php" directly as follows, but it was returned to the original timing at the most.

```
function enqueue_noto_sans_jp() {
    wp_enqueue_style(
        'noto-sans-jp',
        'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Noto+Sans+JP:300,500,700&subset=japanese',
        [],
        wp_get_theme()->get( 'Version' )
    );
}
```

Can I overwrite this with functions.php of the child theme?

Thanks your Help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

John,

Looks like you're on the right track using a child theme, but you only need to change the css part to load in your other fonts and apply css to the page to make use of them.

There is a really good guide to doing that here: https://nudgethemes.com/wordpress-how-to-change-your-theme-font/

Comment: Harry,

Thanks your answer. I tried it and solved the problem.